# Characterization of differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set. Consider a function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $a\in U$.

I need help to prove that the following sentences are equivalents.

> **(a)** There exists a linear map $f'(a):U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $$f(a+v)-f(a)=f'(a)\cdot v+r(v),$$
>   where the "remainder" $r(v)$ satisfies $$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{\|r(v)\|}{\|v\|}=0.$$
>
> **(b)** For each $h\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $a+h\in U$, there exists a linear map $A(h):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A(h)\cdot h=f(a+h)-f(a)$ and $h\mapsto A(h)$ is continuous at $h=0$.

The first sentence is the common definition of differentiability at a point. Could someone give me some ideias to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: The second sentence is Carathéodory's definition.

Comment: Thank you Tony Piccolo. I've found a good reference on this subject: [Frechet vs. Carathéodory](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/259998808_Acosta__Delgado_Frechet_vs_Carathodory), Acosta & Delgado. The proof of Theorem 1 is the answer to my question.

Comment: As to your reference, remember that $\,\otimes \,$ is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication (b)$\Rightarrow$(a) is obvious.

For the proof of (a)$\Rightarrow$(b) we may assume that $n=1$, i.e., that $f$ is a scalar function. The derivative of $f$ at $a$ then appears as gradient $\nabla f(a)$. We therefore have to prove the existence of a vector-valued function ${\bf v}:\>h\mapsto{\bf v}(h)$, defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $h=0$ and continuous at $0$, such that
$${\bf v}(h)\cdot h=f(a+h)-f(a)\qquad(h\in U)\ .$$
The function
$${\bf v}(h):={f(a+h)-f(a)-\nabla f(a)\cdot h\over|h|}\>{h\over|h|}+\nabla f(a)\qquad(h\in\dot U),\qquad{\bf v}(0):=\nabla f(a)$$
fulfills these requirements.

Comment: Christian Blatter, could you comment if, for arbitrary $n$ and $h\neq 0$, is it ok to define $\mathbf{v}(h):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $$\mathbf{v}(h)\cdot x=\langle h,x\rangle\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)\cdot h}{|h|^2}+f'(a)\cdot x?$$(For $h=0$ we keep $\mathbf{v}(0):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\mathbf{v}(0)\cdot x=f'(a)\cdot x$)

Comment: The formula in my answer and the statement in your comment are equivalent.